# How to get array value then implode them into new array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [10 - 20] => 3
    [20 - 30] => 43
    [30 - 40] => 5
    [40 - 50] => 1
    [50 - 60] => 0
    [60 - 70] => 0
)
```

I want to make new array that will send via `json`. Now I have result in json like this(thanks for guys below who answered my question):

```
{"success":true,"data":["3","43","5","1","0","0"]}
```

I need json to be `{"success":true,"data":[3,43,5,1,0,0]}`, cause only with that format `data` show in line chart of highchart

Sorry for my stupid question
Thank You

Comment: what is your output??? Is it an array or a string??

Comment: json_encode(array_values($arr)) would be a solution for your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Here's how you can get your response...

```
$values = array
(
    '10 - 20' => 3,
    '20 - 30' => 43,
    '30 - 40' => 5,
    '40 - 50' => 1,
    '50 - 60' => 0,
    '60 - 70' => 0,
);

$data = array_values($values);

$response = array('sucess' => true, 'data' => $data);

echo json_encode($response);
```

---

Use array_values, this can be done like so:

```
$values = array
(
    '10 - 20' => 3,
    '20 - 30' => 43,
    '30 - 40' => 5,
    '40 - 50' => 1,
    '50 - 60' => 0,
    '60 - 70' => 0,
);

$values = array_values($values);
$data = json_encode($values);

echo data;
```

**Output:**

```
[3,43,5,1,0,0]
```

Comment: nice thanks, but i need to make it into `$arrEmp=[3,43,5,1,0,0];` cause I use json to send that array to chart.If I used your code, the return is not in integer values. In json, your code is like `{"success":true,"data":["3","43","5","1","0","0"]}`. That's why I need it is like `$arrEmp=[3,43,5,1,0,0];`. Thanks so much for your effort

Comment: Ah, I've updated my answer, just use json_encode() to the array into the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might be new to php, Declaration of associative array should be like below

```
$arr=array(
        '[10 - 20]' => 3,
        '[20 - 30]' => 43,
        '[30 - 40]' => 5,
        '[40 - 50]' => 1,
        '[50 - 60]' => 0,
        '[60 - 70]' => 0
    );
```

array('Key'=>value,'key2'=> value);

Write forearch/for/ any loop to get the values, This is useful if you want to extract both key and values at the same time

```
     foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
            echo "$value <br>";
        }
```

If you want to get only values then use array_values($arr)

Comment: @FrayneKonok, Because he might getting data in the server.

Comment: '[10 - 20]' must be '10 - 20'. What i mean

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `array_values`.

**PHP Array**

```
$arr = array("10 - 20" => 3,
             "20 - 30" => 43,
             "30 - 40" => 5,
             "40 - 50" => 1,
             "50 - 60" => 0,
             "60 - 70" => 0
            );
```

Array values from the array.

```
$arr2 = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr2);
```

**Output Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 43
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
)
```

If you need only the values as string then use `implode`.

```
 echo implode(" , ", $arr2);
```

**Result**

```
3 , 43 , 5 , 1 , 0 , 0
```